# How to set and expire cookie value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

In the below I added my code. Can someone help me please to locate the bug?

Here is my code:

```
$_SESSION['browser'] = session_id();

setcookie($expire, $_SESSION['browser'], time() + (60 * 1000), "/");

echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$expire]; die();
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$expire]))
{

    $sql="DELETE * FROM user WHERE id='".$_SESSION['browser']."'";
    $expireqry=mysql_query( $sql);

}
```

Comment: This should be tagged with `php` **only**. You have more chance of getting help when you don't spam tags. Also showing relevant source code help. Example `$expire` where is this defined in your php because I don't see it or know the value assigned to it. Please take your time formatting and planning your question. *"Where is the bug"* What bug? Give more information, explain the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

first, you misusing the `setcookie` function

```
$key = "myCookie";
$value = $_SESSION['browser'];
$expire = time() + (60 * 1000);
setcookie($key, $value, $expire , "/");
```

then remove the `die();`

second, to unset a cookie set the duration to negative number:

```
setcookie('CookieName', null, -1, '/');
//         ^name        ^value ^duration
```

also it seems your if statement logic is wrong

```
 if(!isset($_COOKIE[$expire]))
```

should be

```
 if(isset($_COOKIE[$expire]))
```

and your `$sql` should be

```
 $sql="DELETE * FROM user WHERE id='".$value."'";
```